# How to set language mode of a cell in VS Code Jupyter

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to mix Python and Bash script in a Jupyter notebook.

The Juyter extension, Python kernel and Bash kernel are installed in VS Code.

When I choose python kernel for a notebook, there are several language I can pick for a cell from the bottom right language mode selector. I choose Shell Script, but running the cell got SyntaxError. It doesn't follow the language setting but just use the default language supported by the kernel (Python).

[image: syntax-error-shell-script]

I can make it run successfully by adding magic command `%%bash` at the beginning of the cell. While magic command is used, it seems that the language mode is totally ignored.

[image: run-with-javascript]
The shell script runs successfully even I set the language to JavaScript.

My questions:

- What is the usage of the Cell Language Mode selection? It doesn't take effect according to my experiment.
- The notebook can only pick one kernel, how to choose different language for different cell?

Comment: The notebook can only pick one kernel, how to choose different language for different cell? << as far as I know, you can't